# Optimized database for group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I've got 2 tables, which look something like this

### Device

- device_id (PK)
- other stuffs

### Record (+-500k rows)

- id (autoincrement PK)
- device_id (FK)
- date
- direction (1 or 2)
- amount

And I need queries which will be able to do following things

1. get sum of amounts of one device between two dates
2. get sum of amounts of all devices between two dates (group sum by device_id)
3. get sum of amounts of all devices between two dates and distinguish direction (group sum by device_id, direction)

My queries now look like this

1. `SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM Record WHERE device_id='anId' AND date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date`
2. `SELECT radar_id, SUM(amount) as total FROM Record WHERE date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date GROUP BY device_id`
3. `SELECT radar_id, SUM(amount) as total FROM Record WHERE date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date GROUP BY device_id, direction`

the first query is completed in acceptable time (under 1s), but the other ones takes 30s+.

Is there a way to increase performance?

Comment: Can you share index definitions for the table being queried by the second two queries please?

Comment: Do you have an index on `radar_id` and/or `date`?

Comment: A `group by` on 500,000 rows should not be taking 30+ seconds, unless the rows are really, really wide, your storage is really, really slow (think floppy disks), or you are processing on an old-model watch.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote `radar_id` instead of `device_id`. Only thing a set up are keys (PK in Device table, PK and FK in Record table). So should I set index on `device_id`? And what type of index ?

Comment: And the Record table has 30 columns in total. Can this large amount of columns cause the trouble?

Comment: @Hoostee - The number of columns has very little impact on the issue.